# Conditional hiding of the menu

Tags: menus

I'm trying to hide a menu on a certain page called by it's slug, tried a couple of things but this makes the most sense for me but can't make it to work:

```
// Load Nav Menu
wp_nav_menu( array( 'theme_location' => 'main-nav' ) );

//Remove menu from basket page
if(is_page('basket')) wp_nav_menu( array ('echo' => 
FALSE, 'fallback_cb' => '__return_false') );
```

Comment: Have you tried `if(!is_page('basket'))` then doing your `wp_nav_menu()` call inside the if statement?

Comment: @WebElaine can you clarify your question please (with a code maybe)? thanks

Comment: Your code is still calling `wp_nav_menu()` on the `basket` page. The code I put in the above comment would ensure that `wp_nav_menu()` is not called on that page where you're trying to exclude it.